# Extended WPF StaticExtension – design-time resolving of namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

We introduced the following **custom WPF markup extension** to convert a `static object` to an uppercase `string`.

```
public class StaticToUpperCaseString : StaticExtension
{
    public StaticToUpperCaseString()
    {
    }

    public StaticToUpperCaseString(string member) : base(member)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var str = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        return str?.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

The usage in **XAML** looks like this one – we replaced our previous solution with an unnecessary binding.

```
<UserControl x:Class="…"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:…"
             xmlns:ourNamespace="clr-namespace:…">
   <Label Content={ourNamespace:StaticToUpperCaseString resources:Lang.Message />

   <!-- The previous solution with unnecessary binding -->
   <!-- <Label Content={Binding Source={x:Static resources:Lang.Message}, Converter={…}} /> -->
</UserControl>
```

The code in run-time works fine. The issue is the note of Visual Studio (2017): *Namespace alias 'resources' is not required by code and can be safely removed*. The only usage is the new markup extension, and it is not recognized correctly. There is no issue with the standard `StaticExtension`.

We tried `[TypeConverter(typeof (StaticExtensionConverter))]` attribute with copy of WPF internal `StaticExtensionConverter`, but it does not help.

Comment: I don't get the message `Namespace alias 'resources' is not required by code and can be safely removed` when reproducing your example. Is there any [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=netframework-4.8) in your AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: The namespaces `resources` refers to another project from the same solution. We don't have any `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` in **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

Comment: Have you tried adding the [MarkupExtensionReturnType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextensionreturntypeattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute to your markup extension?